# Cannot see the Windows Forms App template

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am trying creating a new proyect on C# language with a windows form application for desktop, but Visual Studio 2019 does not show the appropiate template. I have installed the following packages:

> .net desktop development
>
> Windows universal development platform
>
> procedure and deployment data

Do I need to install anything else?

Comment: are you looking in the right framework?

Comment: Make sure you selected .NET framework and not .NET Core. Core doesn't (yet) support  windows forms apps

Answer (score 0):

My Visual Studio has recently had the same experience. All of a sudden I cannot select Windows Form (.NET Framework). Only option is .NET CORE.  I fixed the problem.

I am unsure how this happened as I have created and updated programs

NOW if you want to see if this is somehow related to a visual bug try the following:
1) open visual installer
2) click individual components and ensure 4.7.8 SDK is selected and that 4.7.8 targeting is selected.
3) THEN open visual studio and select new project C#, Windows, and Desktop. Scroll down a bit and you might see .NET Framework.
4) If windorms(.NET Framework) still does not show, then select All Languages, Platforms, and Project types and type in the search box .NET Framework. All of a it will show up, and will now be seen under the other selects of C#, Windows, Desktop.
[image]

If the above does NOT work, you will have to do what I did to get step 4 to work.  I had to do a complete uninstall of visual studio, visual code, delete temp files in windows folder, delete temp files in appdata folder, and remove the remaining visual studio folders under appdata. Once everything is uninstalled then rebooted computer and installed new visual studio 2019. It still gave me an issue, so I had to install framework 4.7.2 and now I can see .NET framework, but that would be the old one, so I went back to installer and installed the 4.8 targeting and uninstalled the 4.7.2 Framework.

I can tell you this My visual studio seems to be working better after doing the extreme scrub!

This is the previous screen shots If I select .NET CORE it shows NO winform to work with.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is go to the VS installer and tick the .NET desktop development feature and modify it.

More information here on the Step 3 Note section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score -1):

When you create a new project, make sure you select a windows forms app.  The initial window form1.cs should be in the project view list.

If you are new to C#, stay away from WPF Apps.  They are fun but not easy to create.

Comment: `When you create a new project, make sure you select a windows forms app.`  I think you're missing the problem.  Your last paragraph isn't necessary either.

Comment: The whole point of the question is that the OP can't find the windows forms option in order to select it...